# Program hangs when opening a named pipe for writing in c - use of wait

Tags: c, wait, named-pipes

This is the main in test1.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd1,i, *foo;

  pid_t childpid;
  mkfifo("myfifo1", 0777);
  foo = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
  childpid=fork();
  if (childpid== -1){
      perror("Failed to fork\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid==0) {
      execlp(argv[1],argv[1],(char *) NULL);
      perror("exec failure ");
      exit(1);
    }
    else {
      wait(NULL);
      fd1 = open("myfifo1", O_RDONLY, 0);
      for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
          read(fd1, &foo[i], sizeof(int));
      }
      for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
          printf("%d\n", foo[i]);
      }
   }
  close(fd1);
}
```

and this is the main in test2.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd1, i, *foo;
  fd1 = open("myfifo1", O_WRONLY);
  if (fd1==-1) printf("error\n");
  foo = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      write(fd1, &i, sizeof(int));
  }
  printf("\n");
  close(fd1);
}
```

When I run ./test1 ./test2 the program hangs. I assume that this happens because in test2.c only one end of the pipe opens and the program waits for the other one to do so. However, this never happens because of:

```
wait(NULL)
```

And indeed if I remove this command the program works fine. However, I thought that wait is always useful and it is prevents us from creating zombie processes. Am I wrong at all these? Is there any way to keep the wait command and make the program work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes wait() is to be called by the father process. But why do you want to call it before reading in the FIFO ? You can call it after reading the FIFO. As a side note, the malloc() is useless in test2.c as you don't use foo.

Comment: I thouth that first I have to write and then to read. That's why I called it before reading, to wait until the child writes. Yes you are right about malloc, my bad.

Comment: The read blocks until something is written on the other side of the FIFO

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks a lot